# Integrate 3rd Party CMS With Magento 2

Tags: magento2, integration

I wanted to see if anyone has successfully integrated Magento 2 with a 3rd party CMS yet? If so, was the process easier or more difficult than M1 (taking into account M2's integration API)?

**UPDATE**:
I found this talk by Alan Kent for integrations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzFCjglEWsM This is a great general introduction for introductions. But I'd still like to hear from someone who's successfully completed a CMS integration with Magento 2, even if it's WP.

Comment: Any specifics on CMSes or the types of integrations you're interested in? Wordpress bridges?

Comment: @RyanH. I'm specifically interested in WP, but I wouldn't mind taking a look at the integration. I just want to see what's the general process. Here's more details as to what I'm interested in: https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/223#issuecomment-213953474

Comment: If it helps, I'm currently doing this for Magento 1 and don't find it that difficult, so I imagine it would be the same if not easier using M2. Also, don't go with Wordpress, seriously.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I've seen it done with M1 already, and if you check the github issue link above, I site ECG guides for doing this in M1. I wanted to see feedback for M2. And no, I wouldn't do WP, I just want to see the touch points in M2 is all. lol I'd probably use Concrete5.